# Does Windows 10 screen PPI resizing depend on screen resolution?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, display, resolution, display-settings

For Windows 10, and Windows 7 if different:

Does available intermediates/steps in PPI resizing (that renders crisp text) depend on screen resolution?

I'm looking for a laptop to someone with a bit poor eye sight. Will 1920x1080 give more options than 1600x900, on same size screen (14" laptop) ?

Comment: If my answer missed the mark of what you looking for, provide some feedback  so we can get you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're packing more pixels into the same size screen, the native PPI will be denser, and things rendered at the native resolution will be smaller. So, you will need to use more pixels to render it the same size.

If someone with poor eyesight normally uses magnification (which interpolates the content onto more pixels), they will need more magnification to produce the same size on the higher resolution screen. So in this case, the higher resolution doesn't really buy any benefit.

Also, this interpolation isn't adding additional real content, so you don't get a benefit such as images being more detailed (except in the situation where the higher resolution allows you to display something at its native resolution, where the lower-resolution screen would have to shrink the image to fit).